# Zlib inflate unexpected decompression errors

Tags: c++, compression, zlib, inflate

I am struggling for a few weeks with zlib inflate alghorithm.

I would like to decompress packets from popular game called Tibia. They have compressed it with zlib inflate alghorithms. But it seems something is changed. Can you check it, maybe you will spot something I am missing?

Packet compressed: - **cannot be inflated directly** (its raw huffman fixed coding - probably)

```
DA 22 A6 CB 10 99 5F AA 50 9C 9A AA 90 A8 90 05 B4 2F B5 44 41 C3 B1 28 D7 CA 50 53 8F CB B3 44 A1 3C 35 33 3D A3 58 C1 C8 44 CF C0 40 21 BF 4A 0F
```

Packet decompressed using Reverse Engineering:

```
B4 16 2D 00 59 6F 75 20 73 65 65 20 61 20 6A 61 63 6B 65 74 20 28 41 72 6D 3A 31 29 2E 0A 49 74 20 77 65 69 67 68 73 20 32 34 2E 30 30 20 6F 7A 2E
```

Decompressed packet compressed with zlib deflate using CyberChef deflate / php deflate functions:

```
db 22 a6 cb 10 99 5f aa 50 9c 9a aa 90 a8 90 95 98 9c 9d 5a a2 a0 e1 58 94 6b 65 a8 a9 c7 e5 59 a2 50 9e 9a 99 9e 51 ac 60 64 a2 67 60 a0 90 5f a5 07 00
```

Data matches in a few places, but generally, its different. Do you know what could be the case?

I attach a picture from RE an inflating function: [Screenshot from IdaPro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCcFm.png)

Here are packets in correct order:

1. http://wklej.org/hash/6aee9e223f0/txt/ - inflated correctly
2. http://wklej.org/hash/bd371e7f510/txt/ - inflated correctly
3. http://wklej.org/hash/8f15935dc15/txt/ - inflated correctly

And here is the packet that cannot be inflated...

```
CA059BC6043619009FC9FFFFE831
```

Answer (score 0):

Your packet that cannot be inflated is likely part of a longer stream of compressed data, with other packets preceding it and following it. You need to decompress all of them as a single stream for the decompression to succeed.

Your first example is a portion of a deflate stream that references data that preceded it. So it is part of a larger deflate stream. You need all of the compressed data that preceded that piece in order to decompress that piece. Your last example (CA05...) also references preceding data, so it too is part of a larger stream with compressed data that preceded it.

Comment: To be honest, I have copied input hex stream from memory, have verified it’s length with passed length parameter and then copied output buffer. What’s strange I cannot inflate it in wherever else... it’s zlib inflate, inflate was initiated with -15 param... is it possible that I need to decompress packet by packet with this?... You must know that I have extracted inflate function parameters (also zstream struct contents) on-the-fly from working app

Comment: Compression works by referring to previous data. That packet is referring to  data that must be in a preceding packet. Also that packet has a fixed block that is not the last block, so there must be compressed data that follows.

Comment: Perhaps that is the last packet. In that case, there must be some other means to indicate how many uncompressed bytes there are. The deflate format is self-terminating, but this example does not have a last packet, so it does not self-terminate.